# How do I use autohotkey to make lshift and n do page down and 1

Tags: autohotkey, bind

I want to bind <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to <kbd>PgDn</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>. How do I do this in AutoHotKey? I've tried so many things but I can't get it right.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
LShift & n::Send {PgDn down}{1 down}{PgDn up}{1 up}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
+n::
{
Send {pgdn down}{1 down}
While GetKeyState("w","P")
{
; do nothing
}
Send {pgdn up}{1 up}
} 
return
```